# Custom Input View (Split Keyboard)

Tags: ipad, ios5, keyboard, inputview

I created a custom input view for iPhone, and decided to transition it to work on iPad also. I wanted to make it display like a split keyboard, as it only has a few keys. The problem is, the iPad builds in Undocking of keyboards in the current version, making my keyboard display weird when undocked. How can I either prevent undocking of my custom input view or tell iOS it is a split keyboard so it does not display the line at the bottom.

[image]

The keyboard is a UIView with a clear background color. As subviews of the UIView are the two sides of the keyboard. When undocked, a line is displayed under the clear UIView for the entire keyboard. I either want to get rid of this line or prevent undocking.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever find out how to handle splitting the keyboard?  I just gave up and set autoresizingMask to NO.

Comment: No, sorry. I just dealt with the slightly uglier format.

Comment: Hi, have you tried this in iOS 7?